# Pagination by token in sever side and ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have in the frontend an ember.js application with ember-data to abstract the models and in server side I have a REST Api. When I need a list of the items in the server I do a GET request for `/items` in the case that the list have more than 10 items I receive a json just like that:

```
{
    nextPageToken:"token",
    items:[
          ...
          ]
}
```

The nextPageToken is a token to be used to get the items in the next page, in this particular case making another GET request with the page token included: `/items?pageToken=token`.

I don't know the best way that I can use this tokens to create a page showing the items with a link to the next and the previous pages (storing the token from the previous page) with ember and ember-data.

**UPDATE**

After some research I found a solution to navigate to next page extending the `extractMeta` function in the RESTSerializer to store the nextPageToken as metadata.

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    //...
    // Extract the pageToken and store it as metadata from the desired type.
    extractMeta: function(store, type, payload) {
        store.metaForType(type, { nextPageToken: payload.nextPageToken });
    }
}
```

And then in the controller from my page create a property based in the stored page token.

```
App.ItemsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    //...
    // Get the page token store as metadata from the item model.
    nextPageToken: function(){
        var meta = this.store.metadataFor("item");
        return meta.nextPageToken;
    }.property('item')
}
```

Now it's possible to  use the page token in your template to create a link to the next page.
With that, part of the problem is solved, but I still need to find a solution to navigate to previous pages.